# Sort the array in decreasing order of frequency of occurrence of elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, frequency

Question is to sort the array according to the frequency of the elements. For example, if the input array is

```
   { 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 12 }
```

then modify the array to:

```
   { 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 12, 12, 4, 5 }
```

I wrote the code for this and it is working correctly, but it is using a lot of space and has very high complexity.

I am not satisfied with this solution and the logic I applied for this. Can anyone help to optimize this code or provide a better logic?

My Code is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // this line to work code in visual studio
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /*
     * n = number of integer
     * i = loop variable
     * j = inner loop variable
     * c = number of distinct input
     * buf = temprary storage for input value
     * k = possibility of frequency of any no.
     */

    int n, i, j, c = 0, buf, k;
    int b; //act as flag
    int arr[100] = { 0 };
    int stack[200] = { 0 };
    int top = -1;
    printf("Enter the size of array(integer between 1-100):");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    n *= 2;

    printf("----------Enter the elements in the array----------\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
        b = 0;
        printf("Enter the element:");
        scanf("%d", &buf);
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j += 2) {
            if (arr[j] == buf) {
                arr[j + 1]++;
                b = 1;
            }       
        }
        if (b == 0) {
            c++;
            arr[c * 2 - 2] = buf;
            arr[c * 2 - 1]++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < c * 2; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    //input done in form of (element,times of occurence i.e. frequency),to print array, write this outside of comment: 
    //for (i = 0; i < c * 2; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    for (k = 1; k < n / 2; k++) {   //checking for possible frequencies
        for (j = c * 2 - 1; j > 0; j -= 2) {
            //locations(index) to check in array for frequency
            //left to right, so with same frequency no.,which occurred first will push in last.
            if (arr[j] == k)
                stack[++top] = j; //pushing(index of frequency) into stack in increasing order of frequency     
        }
    }

    //to print stack, write this outside of comment:
    //printf("\nstack\n");
    //for (i = top; i > -1; i--) printf("%d ",stack[i]);

    //printing of elements in there decreasing order of frequency(pop from stack)
    //we have to print element, number of times of its frequency

    printf("\n\n----------Output array in sorted order of there frequency----------\n");
    for (top; top > -1; top--) {        
        for (j = arr[stack[top]]; j > 0; j--)
            printf("%d ", arr[stack[top] - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you limited to `C` only? If `C++` is permitted, where you can use `std::map` and `qsort`, you can do it in 15 lines of code

Comment: Read: [Sort elements by frequency | Set 2](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-elements-by-frequency-set-2/)

Comment: yes because i dont know c++ at all... but you can sugest with c++ for others.. bt i will definetly not able to understand that..

Comment: @Nitkt You can pick a technique from this answer [How to arrange an array in decreasing order of frequency of each number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517195/how-to-arrange-an-array-in-decreasing-order-of-frequency-of-each-number)

Comment: @mvp I tried using std::map and pair and could not do it in less than 17 lines :)

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array by value; RLE the result, turning each span of equals into a pair of the element and the span's length (you can use an auxiliary array to back the second component); sort the pairs in descending order by the second component; there's your result. All in *O(n log n)* time and *O(n)* additional space.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an elegant way to perform this sort in place with a worst case complexity if **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** and average complexity of **O(N.log(N))**.

The method uses the following steps:

- Sort the array by increasing order of values. I use `qsort` with a simple comparison function for this.
- Scan the array for the longest sequence of duplicate values.
- If this sequence is not at the start, shift the values in place and create the sequence at the start.
- Repeat the scan process from the end of the previous step until there are no longer any duplicate sequences.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int int_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    int i1 = *(const int *)p1;
    int i2 = *(const int *)p2;
    return (i1 > i2) - (i1 < i2);
}

void print_array(const char *msg, const int *a, int n) {
    printf("%s: ", msg);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d%c", a[i], " \n"[i == n - 1]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int N = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 200;
    int *array;

    if (N <= 0 || (array = calloc(N, sizeof(*array))) == NULL)
        return 1;

    srand(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        unsigned int x = rand();
        array[i] = x * x % 10;
    }

    print_array("unsorted", array, N);
    qsort(array, N, sizeof(int), int_cmp);
    print_array("  sorted", array, N);
    /* sort by decrasing frequency (assuming N > 0) */
    for (int i = 0;;) {
        /* find the most repeated sequence in [i..N-1] */
        int rep = array[i];
        int n = 1, j, k;
        for (j = k = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[j - n]) {
                rep = array[j];
                k = j + 1;
                n++;
            }
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            /* no more duplicates, f-sort completed */
            break;
        }
        i += n;
        if (k > i) {
            /* shift the repeated sequence in place */
            while (k-- > i) {
                array[k] = array[k - n];
            }
            while (n-- > 0) {
                array[k--] = rep;
            }
        }
    }
    print_array("f-sorted", array, N);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using `qsort` for sorting the values to easily calculate frequencies, and to sort the resulting frequency table by decreasing frequency. When two values have the same frequency, we sort by increasing value.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int cmp_int(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return *(const int *)p1 - *(const int *)p2;
}

typedef struct {
    int val;
    int cnt;
} freq;

int cmp_freq(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const freq *pf1 = (const freq *)p1;
    const freq *pf2 = (const freq *)p2;
    if(pf1->cnt == pf2->cnt)
        return pf1->val - pf2->val;
    return pf2->cnt - pf1->cnt;
}

void frequencySort(int tbl[], int n) {
    // sort values in ascending order
    qsort(tbl, n, sizeof(int), cmp_int);

    // fill frequency table with frequencies
    int nFreq = 0;
    freq *freqTbl = malloc(n*sizeof(freq));
    int val = tbl[0];
    int cnt = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(tbl[i] != val) {
            freqTbl[nFreq].cnt = cnt;
            freqTbl[nFreq].val = val;
            nFreq++;
            val = tbl[i];
            cnt = 1;
        } else {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    freqTbl[nFreq].cnt = cnt;
    freqTbl[nFreq].val = val;
    nFreq++;

    // sort by frequencies
    qsort(freqTbl, nFreq, sizeof(freq), cmp_freq);    

    // refill tbl by frequencies
    int m = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nFreq; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < freqTbl[i].cnt; j++)
            tbl[m++] = freqTbl[i].val;

    free(freqTbl);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 200;
    int *tbl;
    if (n <= 0 || (tbl = malloc(n * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
        return 1;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        tbl[i] = abs(rand()) % 10;

    printf("[%d", tbl[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        printf(",%d", tbl[i]);
    printf("]\n");

    frequencySort(tbl, n);

    printf("[%d", tbl[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        printf(",%d", tbl[i]);
    printf("]\n");

    free(tbl);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the use of subtraction of two integers is fine for small numbers (and the code only tests for numbers in the range 0..9, the epitome of 'small numbers') but would run into integer overflow problems if there were both large positive and large negative numbers in the data.  In `cmp_freq()`, one option might be to use: `return (pf1->val > pf2->val) - (pf1->val < pf2->val);` and similarly for the other comparison in `cmp_freq()` and the one in `cmp_int()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this question very simply and efficiently with some new method and logic.

```
def func(val):
    for key, value in dict1.items():
         if val == value:
             return key
res=[]        
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    lst=list(map(int,input().split()))
    dict1={}
    lst.sort()
    lst2=[]
    for i in lst:
        dict1[i]=lst.count(i)
        lst2.append(lst.count(i))
    lst2.sort()
    lst2.reverse()
    s=''
    for i in lst2:
        k=func(i)
        s=s+((str(k)+" ")*i)
        dict1[k]=0
    s1=s.replace('None',"")
    s2=s1.replace("  ","")
    res.append(s2)
for i in res:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a modified version of [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), but stop halfways, after creating the bucket list.

I made this, inspired by bucket sort. It's weakest link is quick sort, but I it could be modified to use bucket sort. I estimate that the complexity for an array A with length n and maximum value m is O(m + n log n) and if modified with bucket sort instead of qsort it would drop to O(m+n)

```
typedef struct {
    int bucket;
    int index;
} element;

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    element *A = (element *) a;
    element *B = (element *) b;
    return(A->bucket < B->bucket);
}

void sortByFreq(int * arr, int len)
{
    int arrMax=findMax(arr, len);  // O(len)
    element x[arrMax+1];
    for(int i=0; i<=arrMax; i++) {   // O(arrMax)
        x[i].bucket=0;
        x[i].index=i;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)   // O(len)
       x[arr[i]].bucket++;
    qsort(x, arrMax+1, sizeof(element), compare);  //O(len*log(len))

    int k=0;
    for(int i=0; i<=arrMax; i++)  // O(arrMax + len)
        for(int j=0; j<x[i].bucket; j++)
            arr[k++]=x[i].index;
}
```

Comment: I think this code runs into problems if all the elements of the array to be sorted are negative (or, slightly differently, if any of the elements is negative), or if the magnitudes of the integers are huge (1-2 billion, for example), because of the array definition `element x[arrMax + 1];`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, it's correct that it would runt into problems with very high numbers unless you have loads of memory. However, it's pretty easy to modify it to handle negative numbers by just adding an offset of the minimum number.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a *BINARY SEARCH TREE* and while creating BST maintain the count i,e frequency of each coming element in the same BST. This step may take O(nLogn) time if a self-balancing BST is used.
2. Do Inorder traversal of BST and store every element and count of each element in an auxiliary array. Let us call the auxiliary array as ‘count[]’. Note that every element of this array is element and frequency pair. This step takes O(n) time.
3. Sort ‘count[]’ according to the frequency of the elements. This step takes O(nLogn) time if an O(nLogn) sorting algorithm is used.
4. Traverse through the sorted array ‘count[]’. For each element x, print it ‘freq’ times where ‘freq’ is frequency of x. This step takes O(n) time.

The overall time complexity of the algorithm can be minimum O(nLogn) if we use an O(nLogn) sorting algorithm and use a self-balancing BST with O(Logn) insert operation.

[Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-elements-by-frequency-set-2/)

Answer (score 0):

In this program we using selection sort without any inbuilt sequences functions.

package javalearning;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayProgram {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    {
  
   int[] ary = {2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 12};
    sortingwithlen(ary);
}
public static void sortingwithlen(int[] array) {
    int idxcrt = 0; //idxcrt is indexcorretor to know the how many element sorted by frequency. initiailly it will 0
    int eleInd = 0;//elementindex is to store index of frequency element that can obtain in if condition
    while (idxcrt < array.length) {
        int precount = 0;//precount is previous count  and value change in inner loop
        for (int j = idxcrt; j < array.length; j++) {
            int count = 0;//innerloop count used temporary for comparison previous count and start with zero
            for (int i = 0; array.length > i; i++) {
                if (array[j] == array[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > precount) { ///in here each time a count of forloop relate with precount if it greater the precount
                precount = count;///will reaasign of count and eleindex store the counted element index
                eleInd = j;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == array[eleInd]) {
                int temp = array[idxcrt];
                array[idxcrt] = array[eleInd];
                eleInd = idxcrt;
                idxcrt++;
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int* freq_sort_array(int*,int);
int main()
{
  int a[10]={7,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0};     /*input array*/
  int *b,i;
  printf("Input Array\n");
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  printf("%d ",a[i]);
  b=freq_sort_array(a,10);
  printf("\nOutput array\n");
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  printf("%d ",b[i]);
}

                                       /*Function for sorting array based on frequency*/
int* freq_sort_array(int *a,int len)
{
  int i,j,temp,count,k=0,s=0,t=0;
  int *b=(int*)malloc(len*sizeof(int));
  int *c=(int*)malloc(len*sizeof(int));
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
      for(j=i+1;j<len;j++)
      {
          if(a[j]==a[i])
          {
            temp=a[j];
            for(j;j>i+1;j--)
            {
             a[j]=a[j-1];
            }
            a[++i]=temp;
          }
      }
  }
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
      a[j]=a[i];
      count=1;
      if(i!=len-1)
      {
          while(a[++i]==a[j]&& i<len)
            count++;
          i=i-1;
      }
      b[k]=a[j];
      c[k++]=count;
  }
  for(i=1;i<k;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<k-i;j++)
      {
          if(c[j]<c[j+1])
          {
              c[j]=c[j]+c[j+1]-(c[j+1]=c[j]);
              b[j]=b[j]+b[j+1]-(b[j+1]=b[j]);
          }
      }
  }
  for(i=0;i<k;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<c[i];j++)
        a[s++]=b[i];
  }
 return a;
}
```

Comment: Use `<stdlib.h>` (not `<malloc.h>`) to declare `malloc()` et al unless you are explicitly using the extra features provided by `<malloc.h>` (which this code does not).

Comment: My compiler objects to the lines `c[j]=c[j]+c[j+1]-(c[j+1]=c[j]);` and `b[j]=b[j]+b[j+1]-(b[j+1]=b[j]);` because (for example) the code assigns to `c[j+1]` as well as using it, and the order of processing is not defined (there's no sequence point to make it work properly).  The code also leaks memory.  It allocates both `b` and `c` (and doesn't check that the allocation was successful) and does not free them before returning.  I'm not clear what the dubious assignments are doing — I can't recommend this code.  It might work on some systems, but it isn't reliable.