# How to sort array indexes from least frequent to most frequent?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

Suppose I have an array `int[] a = {1, 1, 5, 1, 7, 5}`
I want to sort the array in terms of frequency, like number 7 appeared 1 times in the array, so they go in front, then followed number 5 appeared 2 times, then at last 1, which appeared most frequently.
The expected result should be `{7, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1}`

I tried to write a general structure, and `selection_sort` simply make the array sorted in ascending order. I am not sure if that's useful though.

```
//I know how selection sort works, heres the code I wrote
int selection_sort(int a[], int len) {
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; ++i) {
        pos = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; ++j) {
            if (a[j] < a[pos]) {
                pos = j;
            }
        }
        swap(&a[i], &a[pos]); 
    }
    return a[];
}

a[] = selection_sort(a[], len);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        while (a[i] == a[i + 1]) {
        //dont know what to put here
        }
    }
```

EDIT: the example I had was a bit misleading toward descending sort, I will make another example `{3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2} => {1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4}`
Any value with same frequency can just stay in ascending order, which is why I used a selection sort at the beginning.

Comment: First question: Do you know how that sorting algorithm works? Have you applied it on paper? If you don't know how that array will be manipulated step by step in advance, you should work that out first, and use that as a test case for your code.

Comment: If you're just leaning on `qsort()` then you need to create a look-up table of counts, first. That can be annoying in C, but depending on the allowed range of values you might have shortcuts. You could also take the naïve approach first and just scan the array each time you have to compare values A and B. It'll be slow as a Bubble Sort doped up with tranquilizers, but it will work, and from there you can optimize.

Comment: Related, your example would probably have been driven home better had you reversed the rolls of the values `7` and `5` (i.e. one instance of `5`, two instances of `7`). As it stand now the "result" looks like a simple descending sort, and judging by your description that certainly isn't a guarantee in all cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort the array in decreasing order of frequency of occurrence of elements in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129964/sort-the-array-in-decreasing-order-of-frequency-of-occurrence-of-elements-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to store the frequency in a separate table. The simple/naive implementation of such a table is something like `int count [10];`, if we only expect values from `0` to `9`.

In this case, you'll have to iterate through the data once to map the occurrences:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof a/sizeof *a; i++)
  count[ a[i] ]++;
```

After that, `count` will look like `{0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0}`.

You can now sort `a` based on this table, by having your sort algorithm comparing items in that table:

```
if( count[ a[x] ] < count[ a[y ] ) 
  /* then place a[x] before a[y] */
```

There's more efficient and advanced ways to do this, but the above should suffice for beginner-level purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the frequencies (along with the information, to which index each frequency points to); then running length decode each frequency to the index.

If the indices and frequencies are short enough, you can pack both values to same word: `uint32_t sorted_key = (frequency << 16) + index;`. Sorting these keys will preserve (some) order of the indices as well.

In essence you need to sort only the tuples (1,3), (5,2), (7,1) by the frequency and in case of tie, by index. Afterwards, (1,3) is decoded to [1 1 1], (5,2) is decoded to [5 5] and (7,1) is decoded to [7].